# About performance of qgis with big layer or a lot of layer

Tags: qgis, layers, features, api

does anyone has a feedback on the performance of a big layer
by exemple :
I have a layer with 100 features, each feature contains specifics attributes with dynamic data, the data change each second

My question :
is it better to have this kind of layer or is it better to have 100 small layer with just one feature

is it a problem for qgis to manage a lot of layer ?

update :
here is some more information, the feature i use has 8 parameters ( int, double, string ) each is updated every second, 1 layer for 1 feature

I think the maximum I will have is 50 layers
My computer is a dual xeon, 8go of ram, no database, everything is in memory
the application is coded in c++/qt 4.8.5 with qgis api c++ 2.8.2

Comment: This might get flagged as being too broad as the performance of QGIS can depend on a number of factors, not just within QGIS. E.g. memory and processing speed of your computer will have an effect. It could also depend on how many fields you have, how you are computing the changes (by field calculator, python script...), if you're using a shapefile from a local directory or a database etc etc etc. So quite a few variables :). Personally, I use the minimum number of shapefiles I can. If one has too much data and slows QGIS then I will split it to another shapefile. So good luck!

Comment: i add information in my question , but i am agree with you there is a lot of externals parameters

Comment: 100 records is a *tiny* shapefile. Shapefiles do **not** support the concept of "dynamic data", so this is your real problem -- you're trying to implement a realtime data layer with an incompatible format. You should probably change the question to address your realtime requirement.